# Rectangle (bbox) around non masked values in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am looking for a solution to create a bounding box (rectangle) around non-masked pixels of an image in Google Earth Engine.

In this simple example, the first image has only some non-masked pixels within the larger region of interest (roi). I would like ot automatically create a rectangle that includes all of the existing values within the roi.

```
// cloud maks
function cloudMask(image){
  var QA60 = image.select('QA60');
  return image.updateMask(QA60.lt(1));
}

var S2dat = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
        .filterDate('2018-06-01', '2018-06-15')
        .filterBounds(roi)
        .map(cloudMask)
        .first();

Map.setCenter(126.42, 72.80, 6);
Map.addLayer(S2dat.select("B2").clip(roi));
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c8e8a6b86f8fb8023151f4c145a36901

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `reduceToVector` for this:

```
var bounds = S2dat.select("B2").mask().gt(0).selfMask().addBands(1).reduceToVectors({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(), 
  geometry: roi, 
  scale: 500, 
  geometryType: "bb"
})
Map.addLayer(bounds)
```

The mask of the image is 0s and 1s.  You want the pixels with mask > 0, and you want to exclude the pixels with mask == 0 (`.selfmask()`).  You have to provide another band (`.addBands(1)`), just because the reducer needs something to do.

If you want the final polygons merged, just take a `bounds()` of the geometry of that collection.

If your data is messy (lots of discontinuous parts), it might be cleaner to just reduce a `pixelLonLat` image:

```
var extents = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().updateMask(S2dat.select("B2").mask())
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.minMax(), roi, 500)
var bounds2 = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(extents.values(["longitude_min", "latitude_min", "longitude_max", "latitude_max"]))
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/cf5f3eb23edf22096dd1e038fd9e160a